# addcslashes escaping capital letters

Tags: php, string, ascii

The following is my code sample:

```
<?php
   echo addcslashes('ABC','\0..\37');
?>
```

My output is

```
\A\B\C
```

As per the documentation, `\0...\37` would escape the ASCII values between 0 and 31. But I find that capital alphabets whose ASCII values more than 31, are being escaped here. When i tried the with small letters, it is working correctly.

What should i add to make addcslashes function work for given ASCII characters?

Comment: PHP won't interpret escape sequences in single quotes (see [string documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes so that `\`-escapes will work properly:

```
echo addcslashes('ABC', "\0..\37");
```

With single quotes `'\0..\37'` is interpreted as `\` + range `0..\` + characters `37`.

For example all capital alphabets will be within that range `0..\`, which is why they were being escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes for the `$charlist` parameter:

```
echo addcslashes('ABC', "\0..\37");
```

With [single quoted string](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) backslash does not represent a special character sequence.

Also see the manual for [double quoted strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: Thanks. But why is it working differently for single slashes

Comment: Because with [single quotes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) backslash does not represent a special character sequence. See manual for [double quoted strings](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)